# Listbox into an Access DB

Tags: database, vb.net, listbox

So far I have this, which doesn't work. I think I'm off on the wrong path here. Basically I'm trying to transfer all of the items of a list box to separate columns of an Access DB named CalcOps, with the columns of "NumOne, Operator, NumTwo, Result). The list box can currently have 10 total list items, all of which should be transferred when the button is clicked (ButtonDBSave). The list box items are put together from separate text boxes and the operator that is clicked on is transferred to the list box via Listbox.tag. Not getting any errors...or anything else.

```
Private Sub ButtonDBSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonDBSave.Click


    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim dbProvider As String
    Dim dbSource As String

    dbProvider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    dbSource = "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\CalcDB.accdb"

    con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource


    Dim arr As New List(Of String)
    Dim cmdText As String = "INSERT INTO NumOne ()"
    Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(cmdText)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    con.Open()

    With cmd.Parameters
        .Add("@NumOne", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = NumOne.Text


    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: CalcOps is the name of your table, so it's not a Parameter.  You are missing a connection string for your cmd object and you never execute the query (which would produce an error).  Very unclear what the ListBox is doing in this code, but ListBox1.SelectedItem would be wrong, it should be ListBox1.Items(i).ToString.  The For-Loop should be .Count - 1.  That should have produced an error.

Comment: Thanks, I have no idea what I'm doing. I've been reading and reading literally all day.

Comment: Simplify it.  Start by just trying to save one thing and return that one thing, and once you get that going, then move on to lists, etc.

Comment: I've update things a bit to try and simplify, DB is in the bin folder, getting this error "Additional information: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0Data Source=|DataDirectory|\CalcDB.accdb' provider is not registered on the local machine"

Comment: You are going to have to get yourself a tutorial.  StackOverflow is not that place.

Comment: You know of any for this situation, because I've been looking all day.